# Count number of elements contained in array fields in a composite object

Tags: javascript, lodash

```
var obj = { 0:["abc", "pqr"], 1:["xyz"] };
```

I am expecting count value to be 3.

My function -

```
   var countNumberOfElementsInArrayGivenObject = function (input: Object) {
                           let count = 0;
                           _.forEach(input, function (value, key) {
                               count += value.length
                           });

                           return count;
                       }
```

This works, but I am looking for better solution using lodash lib functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`_.sumBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.6#sumBy) after getting the values of the object.

```js
var obj = { a: ["abc", "pqr"], b: ["xyz"] };
var total = _(obj).values().sumBy('length');
console.log(total);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/lodash/4.16.3/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

use [`_.flatten`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#flatten)

```
var res = _.chain(obj)
    .values() // to array of values
    .flatten() 
    .size()
    .value()
```

**NOTE**

it can be expencive for many elements, it is better to use [the `_.sumBy` solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41158940/1988157).

Comment: The flatten will be an expensive step for such a simple operation.